# How do you hardcode the format of sudo hwclock

Tags: raspberry-pi, clock

Hey there so I just received a new RTC for my Raspberry Pi.

When I run this command:

```
sudo hwclock
```

The output looks like the following:

```
2018-01-08 13:06:5.441956+0100
```

But, on my other Raspberry Pi the output looks like:

```
mon 08 jan 2018 13:06:05 CET -0.082820 seconds
```

How do I change the output of `sudo hwclock`?
How do you hardcode the format of `sudo hwclock`?

Comment: CET? Europe? Please tell us your country and which command are you using on the other rpi.

Comment: CET Europe. Live in Denmark. Using the same command (?) on both RPi's which is `sudo hwclock`

Comment: `sudo tzconfig`
 , are you able to change for `Europe/Denmark`? Does it work for you? (I think you have to logout and login after `tzconfig`
, cant remember)

Comment: It's already set to Europe/Denmark.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, the environment variable `LANG`

```
 LANG=nl_BE  sudo hwclock
```

It may depend on the configuration of `sudo` if environment variables are passed through. `sudo` also has the option `-E` for passing the environment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/225098)

Comment: Strange, I thought the OP wanted to know what could influence the date format. Must have been dreaming.

Comment: Yes, LANG is one of the locale environment variables that can affect the output of time values. LC_TIME can override LANG, and LC_ALL will override any other locale variables if set. Another source of differences might be the timezone specification: if the system timezone is specified as e.g. Europe/Berlin, it may result in different output vs. specifying CET-1CEST or similar. A third source is the version of the `hwclock` command used: perhaps the programmer has hardcoded the output format to use numeric timezones in a newer version?

Answer (score 0):

The output from `hwclock` is actually based on distro and version.

- For *ubuntu 18.04+* you will see it like

  ```
  2018-01-08 13:06:5.441956+0100
  ```
- and for older versions you will get :

  ```
  mon 08 jan 2018 13:06:05 CET -0.082820 seconds
  ```

So it is about the version I'd say.

Comment: Welcome to the community. The question is "how do I make `hwclock` show the output I want`. Can you please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/735595/edit) your question to clarify how exactly this answers the question?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/437008)